# Android: Adding a dialog to a Layout in java

Tags: java, android, android-layout, dialog

I have a normal dialog on a sample project running upon application start. Added programmatically.

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alert.setTitle("Web Page");

    WebView wv = new WebView(this);
    wv.loadUrl("https://url.com/");
    wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);

            return true;
        }
    });

    alert.setView(wv);
    alert.setNegativeButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    alert.show();
```

My query is for help in adding this dialog on a Relative Layout which has also been added programmatically.

```
@SuppressLint({"ViewConstructor"})
public class MainLayout extends RelativeLayout implements      View.OnClickListener {
public static int height;
public static int width;

public Activity activity;
public LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParam;
public AlertDialog alertDialog;

/* Buttons /

@SuppressLint({"ResourceAsColor", "NewApi"})
public MainLayout(Activity paramActivity) {
    super(paramActivity);

    Display localDisplay = paramActivity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point localPoint = new Point();
    localDisplay.getSize(localPoint);

    width = localPoint.x;
    height = localPoint.y;

    this.activity = paramActivity;
```

.
.
.`

When I merge the two I get Layout Exceptional Errors.
Any help or work around will be appreciated.

Comment: Post the errors you get.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Explain a bit better and add the logcat.

Comment: One moment as I add both...

Answer (score 0):

First I'll point out what I wanted to achieve... Upon app opening, there should be a pop up dialogue which fetches text notification my web: [image: This way]

The mistake I made was placing the dialog in the MainLayout Class instead of the inflater Main Class:[image]

Thanks for the help. :)